# How add a scroll bar in the scroll view of xamarin ios ?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, scrollview

I have a scroll view in xaml page. But I could not find a scroll bar associated with it. No property is available to show the scroll bar. Should I add a custom renderer class to display scroll bar?

Comment: `UIScrollView` doesn't have a scrollbar - it really just has an indicator showing where you are relative the content size. AFAIK Xamarin.Forms (which I assume you're using, since you tagged XAML) doesn't provide any way to show that scroll indicator. But `UIScrollView` has a [`FlashScrollIndicators`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/UIKit.UIScrollView.FlashScrollIndicators()/) which might help in a custom renderer but it only briefly shows the scroll indicator, and doesn't make it constantly visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIScrollView` do not have "Win32-style" always on scrollbars, there is a scroll indicator that can to shown while you are scrolling to show the user where they are within the scrollable view.

In a custom renderer (`ScrollViewRenderer`) you could set items like:

```
scrollView.ShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true;
scrollView.ShowsVerticalScrollIndicator = true;
scrollView.IndicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyle.Black;
scrollView.ScrollIndicatorInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0, 30, 0, 30);
```

But, again, the built-in scroll indictor will only be shown on screen while the user is actually scrolling.

[image]

If you need them on screen all the time you would need to draw the scrollbars yourself.

Note: This is the same behavoir as the OS-X scroll view.

Comment: Hi, I have to show there is content in the scroll view while the page is appearing. Now since there is no scroll bar on appearing, there is no indication that content is there beyond the screen. Scroll bar is appearing when we start scrolling. Without using custom renderer can i show that the page is scrollable?

Comment: @Krishna 1) Zoom the UIScrollView out till the user can see content, never leave the user an entire view that is blank, 2) Programmatically scroll the user to the content via `ScrollRectToVisible`  3) Design/place your content so it is **not** leaving blank areas that are as large/larger than the view size, 4) Custom Renderer to add scrollbars....