# How to show always VerticalScrollBar in ScrollView of Xamarin?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am very beginner in Xamarin. I am creating an application which will support all three major platform UWP, Android, iOS. I want to show HorizonralScrollBar Indicator always in my application. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How add a scroll bar in the scroll view of xamarin ios ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835067/how-add-a-scroll-bar-in-the-scroll-view-of-xamarin-ios)

Comment: The title requests to show a Vertical Scrollbar, whereas you in question ask how to show a horizontal one. What do you want?

Comment: Showing scrollbar always you mean on every page?

Comment: months later i still can't seem to find any convenient way to have a visible scrollbar on a scrollview, vertical or horizontal. lame limitations like this — seemingly basic features nowhere to be found — are making me want to drop Xamarin as soon as i can.

Answer (score 4):

In your xml, set VerticalScrollBarVisibility to "Always".
`<ScrollView VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always"></ScrollView>`